# Mapped types + function parameters enigma

Tags: typescript, redux

The current example below still doesn't exactly do what I want (example: a function which manipulates redux reducers). This function outputs the desired type but allows undesired input (the `c: 'hello'`). The currying seemed really needed here to trick the compiler with the order of the things.

```
type Reducer<State> = (s: State, p: any) => State

const reducerMap = <State>(s: State) => <
  ScopedReducers extends { [k in keyof State]: Reducer<State[k]> }
>(
  input: ScopedReducers
): { [k in keyof ScopedReducers]: Reducer<State> } => {
  return undefined as any
}

const state = { a: 1, b: "2" }
const mapped = reducerMap(state)({
  a: state => state + 1,
  b: state => state + "_",
  c: "hello",
})
```

- `ScopedReducers` is an object with some relationship with `State` (each key is a `Reducer<State[k]>`), yet with a free part of his own (the reducer payload). `ScopedReducers` should only contain keys which `State` also has.
- If I assign `ScopedReducers` directly to its constraint, its function input validates correctly. If I put an extra key not present in `State`, the compiler will err, as expected.

  - On the other hand, I can't reuse the `payload` part from the Reducer when constructing the function return. This type is erased to `any`.
- If I say `ScopedReducers` extends its constraint, its type is not erased and can be used when composing a dynamic mapped function return.

  - On the other hand, since now I'm using `extends`, the function parameter now accepts extraneous keys (ex: `e : 2`). Relationship validations still work on the applicable keys.

And the "real beast" is the last function from this file on [this personal project](https://github.com/wkrueger/redutser/blob/master/src/subdomain.ts), which also has a "keyof" issue I think probably can't be solved...

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve ? what do `h` and `v` represent ? What is the expected behavior of the function ?

Comment: edited with a less cryptic example :)

Comment: I had a similar working example that produced an error for this case, but since I wasn't sure what you were looking for I didn't post it, I'll check if is applicable and post it when I wake up tomorrow morning if someone else doesn't do it by then :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without worrying too much about what's going on in your code and taking your question at face value, I think you are trying to make `ScopedReducers` a so-called [exact type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), which contains *exactly* the specified properties: no less and no more.  Unfortunately such types don't yet  exist in the language.  Luckily, since [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) were introduced in TypeScript 2.8, there is now [a way](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-368244671) to require that a type parameter act like an exact type, which is all you need in your case.

Let's introduce `Exactify<T, X>`:

```
type Exactify<T, X extends T> = T & {
  [K in keyof X]: K extends keyof T ? X[K] : never
}
```

and imagine what happens when a generic type parameter `X` is constrained to `Exactify<T, X>` for some `T`:

```
declare function exactlyFoo<X extends Exactify<Foo, X>>(x: X): void;
```

What does it mean that `X extends Exactify<Foo, X>`?  If `X` has only the same keys as `Foo`, then `X extends Exactify<Foo, X>` means just `X extends T & X`, which is just `X extends T`.  But if `X` has even one key (say `extraKey`) not present in `Foo`, then `X extends Exactify<Foo, X>` becomes `X extends T & X & { extraKey: never }`, which is impossible unless the property `extraKey` has type `never`.  In practice this means you can't add an extra key.

If I apply `Exactify<>` to your code, it becomes:

```
const reducerMap = <State>(s: State) => <
  ScopedReducers extends Exactify<
  { [k in keyof State]: Reducer<State[k]> }, ScopedReducers>>(
    input: ScopedReducers
  ): { [k in keyof ScopedReducers]: Reducer<State> } => {
  return undefined as any
}
```

And using it:

```
const state = { a: 1, b: "2" }
const mapped = reducerMap(state)({
  a: state => state + 1,
  b: state => state + "_",
  c: "hello", // error!
})
```

You get an error at property `c` as desired.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: whoa now thats the kind of thing that I'd absolutely never find by myself! Worked great! A great thank you!
My particular case still has another problem, but that's case for another question